# JAVA trying to find positions of the year. Not Working

Tags: java, arrays, json, string, if-statement

I have a small program that reads a json file that gives the
weather, time, temp, wind, ect. I need to calculate the average
tempature for 2009 through 2015. The years are in an array, and are in
length, around 60k. I am trying to write a small loop that will first
find the position of the first instance of the year 2009 and then
the last instance of the year 2009. Then I can run my
average temp loop through that, but I am running into an issue as seen
below.

`place` will be the index of the array. However, no matter how I run my
code, it always equals -1, rather than giving me the position of
the index in the array. Both arguments in the `if` statements are
strings.

So what am I doing wrong?

```
String twozerozeronine = "2009";
int place = -1;
for (int a = 0; a < years.size(); a++){
    if (years.get(a) == twozerozeronine){
        place = 1; 
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(place);
```

Comment: `if (years.get(a) === twozerozeronine)` Try this.

Comment: @sanA Java does not have a triple-equals operator.

Comment: `if (years.get(a) .equals(twozerozeronine))`

Comment: `if (years.get(a).equals(twozerozeronine))` Try this.   Thanks for correction @khelwood

Comment: thanks the .equals helped but then we noticed that we also had an error in our syntax that made it mess up! Solved now.

Comment: Hey Sofelia. I see you had a bit of a rough ride on SO recently. If you want any advice on using the platform or editing etiquette, feel free to ping me or [drop me an email](https://blog.jondh.me.uk/about/).

Answer (score 0):

```
years.get(a) == twozerozeronine
```

checks whether the object on the left side of the operator and the object on the right side of the operator are the very same. In your case they might be similar, but will never be the very same.

You will need to check whether they are similar instead:

```
years.get(a).equals(twozerozeronine)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `equals()` method to compare the value of the Strings.

Like: `if ( years.get( a ).equals( twozerozeronine ) ){`

The `==` operator compares the Object references (in your case, both are not equal) whereas `equals()` method compares the actual string values (in your case, the string values are "2009").

Comment: Please do not summarily roll back good edits @VNT.